# How do I integrate JProfiler 7.2.2 with Scala IDE 3.0.0 on OS/X 10.8.3 64-bit?

Tags: jprofiler, scala-ide

JProfiler integrates fine into IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4 and Eclipse 4.2.2 but it does not integrate into Scala IDE 3.0.0.

I have fresh installs of Scala IDE 3.0.0 (based on Eclipse Indigo) and JProfiler 7.2.2. and have enabled the "Profile" actions under "Window->Customize Perspective".

The profile buttons are all disabled, and there is no JProfiler entry in the Preferences dialog.

There are no obvious error messages, but ~/.jprofiler7/config.xml does not contain the integration entries for eclipse 3.7. Including the successful IntelliJ and Eclipse 4.2.2 entries the relevant section looks like this:

```
<integrations>
  <netbeansConfig targetDir="" />
  <eclipseConfig targetDir="/Applications/eclipse-4.2.2" />
  <ideaConfig targetDir="/Users/richard/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea12" />
  <jdeveloperConfig targetDir="" />
</integrations>
```

Is Scala IDE 3.0.0 supported?

**Edit**

The JProfiler integration installs these files under the Eclipse application folder:

```
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/META-INF
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/eclipse3-jprofiler.jar
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/bundle_obj.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/eclipse_launcher.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/java_app.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/java_applet.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/jprofiler.png
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/julaunch.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/julaunchpgn.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/icons/swt_launcher.gif
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/jprofiler.properties
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/plugin.properties
/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse/plugin.xml
```

I also noticed that there is no integration zip file in the JProfiler installation for Eclipse 3.7:

```
/Applications/jprofiler7/integrations/eclipse33-jprofiler.zip
/Applications/jprofiler7/integrations/eclipse34-jprofiler.zip
/Applications/jprofiler7/integrations/eclipse35-jprofiler.zip
/Applications/jprofiler7/integrations/eclipse36-jprofiler.zip
/Applications/jprofiler7/integrations/eclipse42-jprofiler.zip
```

**Edit 2**
None of these log files mention profiler:

```
$ locate log | grep eclipse | grep "\.log$"
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse 4.2 Classic.app/Contents/Profile/configuration/1365105032164.log
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse 4.2 Classic.app/Contents/Profile/configuration/1365105063165.log
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse 4.2 Classic.app/Contents/Profile/configuration/1365185736428.log
/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.update/install.log
/Users/richard/.eclipse/610389151/configuration/1345715718730.log
/Users/richard/coursera/progfun/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.views.log
/Users/richard/workspaces/eclipse37/.metadata/.log
/Users/richard/workspaces/eclipse42/.metadata/.log
```

**Edit 3**
This is the content of the workspace's .metadata.log file"

```
!SESSION 2013-04-10 09:48:50.570 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.0.0-vfinal-20130326-1146-Typesafe
java.version=1.6.0_43
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/richard/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/richard/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2013-04-10 09:49:10.083
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
```

Comment: If there is no "JProfiler" entry in the preferences dialog, the plugin was not loaded. Please check if the "dropins" folder of your IDE contains the JProfiler plugin and if yes if there are any messages regarding that plugin in the IDE log.

Comment: There is a folder called: /Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse but no "dropins" folder. The Eclipse 4.2.2 integration did create a "dropins" folder, the IntelliJ integration doesn't seem to have modified the IntelliJ application at all.

Comment: There are no errors containing "jprofiler" in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench ... but I'm not sure how the JProfiler integration would know which workspace to install into because the integration happens when the IDE is closed. The IDE is not producing any errors when it starts.

Comment: For IntelliJ, the plugin is copied to the user dir, not the installation dir, for eclipse the plugins are in the installation dir. The eclipse integration for 3.7 and 3.6 are the same. There must be some kind of message in the log why the JProfiler plugin cannot be loaded.

Comment: Which logfile would contain the message? I've checked all the log files containing "eclipse" and ending in ".log" and I can't see any mention of jprofiler. Perhaps Eclipse isn't attempting to load it? I tried renaming the /Applications/jprofiler7 folder to see if Eclipse would error on startup, but it just started as normal.

Comment: I copied the eclipse36-jprofiler.zip to eclipse37-jprofiler.zip and re-ran the Eclipse 3.7 integration. The eclipse entry in the configurations section is now: <eclipseConfig targetDir="/Applications/eclipse" /> but the profiling buttons are still not enabled.

Comment: If it is in the plugins directory, it must attempt to load it. The log file is in the workspace directory, under .metadata\.log. Renaming /Applications/jprofiler7 would have no effect, the plugin is self-contained and the JProfiler is only called when you start to profile something.

Comment: I've added the contents of the .metadata/.log file above - I started a new .log file as the old one contained old messages accumulated over several months. There is no mention of jprofiler in either the old or new .log file.

Comment: I also tried installing Scala IDE 3.0.0 and JProfiler 7.2.2 on a 64-bit Linux (Debian) machine with the same result.

Comment: So we have never tried this. Usually, eclipse based IDEs work just like that, but apparently not in this case. I've created an issue for this.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try again when there is a new version.

Comment: I seem to also be having this issue with Scala IDE 3.03 and JProfiler 8.0.7. Does anybody know of a fix?